# Supermicro server SC733T Super Doctor 5, RAID HDD status

Tags: raid, monitoring, supermicro

I have a simple Supermicro SC733T server. There are 2  SATA HDD disks in the server. I configured RAID1 with the 2 HDD (TOSHIBA HDWD110). The raid controller is Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset SATA RAID Controller. The OS used is Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS.

Then I set up Super Doctor 5 (it has Web interface) provided by Supermicro for monitoring health of servers. It shows all info, except for the HDD drives. It says that the status is `unknown`. When I enter the RAID Controller configuration during the startup using Ctrl-I it shows info and that the status is OK.

I want to see the current status of HDD disks through the Super Doctor 5 utility. I also followed the instructions on how to setup SNMP extension during the Super Doctor 5 installation but it did not help.

It's really annoying, since if I were using software raid then I could see the health of the disks using the OS tools, but here I use hardware raid controller and it does not provide the information in the specialized utility provided by Supermicro.

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: There is not hardware RAID. There is Fake RAID.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy Any suggestions how to solve the problem then?

Comment: Don't use Fake RAID.

Answer (score 1):

supermicro doctor manuals says it only shows non raided harddrives health.

EDIT: Starting from the V5 they can do not only individual disks, but RAID groups as well.

https://www.supermicro.com/en/solutions/management-software/superdoctor

*Hardware Monitoring: fan speed, temperature, voltage, chassis intrusion, redundant power failure, power consumption, disk health, **RAID health**, and memory health.*

Comment: Adding a quote and a link to the relevant section of the manual would be an improvement of this answer.

Comment: I added the URL. Guy's original statement is actually incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

The SM SuperDoctor 5 user guide (v1.7a) states on page 13:

> Monitoring  SMART  health  supports  non-RAID  internal  hard  disks  and  does  not  support USB hard disks and flash disks. To use this function, install the smartctl utility program first.

Unfortunately, the SD5 user guide (and software) is only available if you provide your company details on [this](https://www.supermicro.com/SwDownload/UserInfo.aspx?sw=0&cat=SD5) website.

Answer (score -1):

Does Super Doctor 5 provides a Command Line Utility? If it does you can create a custom shell script and use snmp extend

```
extend raid_status /bin/bash /script/location/raid_status
```

You will query the results from your monitoring server with the following string

```
snmpget -v 2c -c <community-script> <target-server> NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::'nsExtendOutputFull."raid_status"'
```